# Use of "on the grounds" in the context of a government decision

Tags: expressions

The following sentence comes from a foreign publication. It sounds wrong to me, but I am not a native English speaker. Is it grammatically and idiomatically correct?

> The government banned demonstrations at the square on the grounds of safety and public order in a more polarized political atmosphere.

Comment: Hello, A Karp, and welcome to EL&U. I have edited your question a bit and added some formatting to help separate the text of your question from the text of the quotation you are asking about. I had a bit of trouble understanding precisely what you wanted to ask about, so please check the revised wording to see whether it matches your intention. If you don't like the revised wording, you can roll your question back to the original wording, if you like. But I think the question would be better if you could give a brief account of what concerns you about the phrase "on the grounds." Thanks!

Comment: Understand that "on the grounds of" is an idiom that means "because of concerns about".  (Though frankly the hidden meaning of the term is often "to justify an otherwise unjustifiable action".)

Answer (score 1):

["on the grounds of safety and"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20the%20grounds%20of%20safety%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22on%20the%20grounds%20of%20safety%20and%22)
About 7,480 results

has a good showing at Google Books (use it instead of vanilla Google), and I don't see any reasons for suspecting it.

However, I'd use

"demonstrations **in** the square"
About 5,900 results

instead of

"demonstrations at the square"
9 results

thus something was fishy here indeed :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the source of confusion might be the meaning of the word *ground**s***.

LDOCE says (def. 3):

[grounds](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ground_1)

> [ plural] a good reason for doing, believing, or saying something
>
> on (the) grounds of something
>
> Flying was ruled out on grounds of cost.

So *on the grounds of* is simply idiomatic (and as Marius pointed out, it is correct).

Comment: This idiom appeared again last week. Should be "on grounds"? Although Lucky put the "the" in parenthesis Indicating optionality perhaps, I think there should not be one there at all. What do you think?

Comment: @AKarp The quote above is from the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English (on-line version) - and it indeed indicates that the definite article is optional in the phrase, or the way I see it, its usage depends on the context. Consider this sentence: "they called for a retrial on the grounds of the new evidence" from [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ground?q=grounds#ground__7). The question about the article can be a good one on its own, if you write it in such a way that it follows the help centre guidelines (IMO).